# Could Aquaman control Cthulhu?

Tags: dc, cthulhu-mythos, aquaman

Aquaman has control over all creatures of the ocean. Cthulhu is a creature of the sea (arguably). Can aquaman control Cthulhu? If not is it because Aquaman is not powerful enough or because Cthulhu does not count?

From Comic-Vine

> Although this power is most often and most easily used on marine life, Aquaman has demonstrated the capacity to *affect any being that **lives upon the sea** or even any being evolved from marine life*.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

## Cthulhu! I command you to do my bidding!

[image: Aquaman, in a commanding pose, stands on top of Cthulhu's head. Cthulhu is green, scaly and enormous. Waves crash around Cthulhu's writhing tentacles.]

Comment: He does not "live" in the sea and he comes from the stars. Iä! Iä! Cthulhu Fhtagn!

Comment: But he does sleep there. In other news: Why the downvote?

Comment: I do not question the motives of Great Cthulhu.  Also, I did not downvote.

Comment: @Pureferret - The Holy Jihad Against Any Crossover Questions! Muad'Dib!

Comment: I think the real answer is how would Cthulhu control Aquaman -- before eating him.

Comment: @DKV now, why did you have to go and drag me into this?

Comment: I think this is the best question on SciFi Stackexchange that I have ever seen! Iä, Iä, Ph'nglui Mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn

Comment: Isn't there an episode of Justice League (animated) that had Aquaman (and others) fighting Cthulhu and other Lovecraftian monsters?

Comment: @rstyskel yes and its excellent

Comment: In the pic shown, Cthulhu is thinking, "where is the buzzing sound coming from?"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Isn't Cthulhu a god/alien? He may currently in the sea, but he's not a "creature of the sea" - and will not always be that way.

> Cthulhu is a Great Old One and is by far the most prominent member of the group. He currently lies in death-like sleep in the sunken city of R'lyeh somewhere in the Southeast Pacific Ocean. "When the stars are right", **R'lyeh will rise from the sea, never to sink again**, and Cthulhu will awaken and revel across the world, "ravening for delight" ([src](http://www.yog-sothoth.com/wiki/index.php/Cthulhu)).

He's also not necessarily fully "aquatic" biologically: "simultaneous pictures of an octopus, a dragon, and a human caricature". And I'm not sure that Octopoid physiology fully implies aquatic evolution.

So the answer is "**NO**".

Please note that "Great Cthulhu is one of the Water Beings" is from Derleth's scheme, NOT from Lovecraft himself.

Comment: Is this the case for the DC version of Cthulhu (if such a version exists)? He is 'part' octopus.

Comment: @Pureferret - part "Earth aquatic" octopus, or part "Alien of absolutely unknown evolutionary origin" octopus? I'm not familiar with DC one

Comment: I've updated the question. Is it possible that Aquaman would be able to control Cthulhu whilst he is a 'creature...that lives upon the sea'?

Comment: @Pureferret - Can he control humans in submarines? I think the situation is identical with Cthulhu

Comment: Submariners live at most 6 months under the sea, however Cthulhu has been there for uncountable eons. Secondly he physically lives next to water, 'breathing' it in, the ocean all around him/her/it. Submariners on the other hand live in a relatively dry tin can.

Comment: @Pureferret - I thought he was dead, not beathing?

Comment: That which may eternal lie, perhaps even death may die?

Comment: Additionally, in _At the Mountains of Madness_, it is recorded that when Cthulhu and his spawn arrived on Earth, they drove the 'Elder Things' off of dry land.  They probably wouldn't have done that if they themselves were aquatic.

Answer (score 14):

Cthulhu is definitely not an aquatic creature, despite the octopoid head. (Lovecraft sketched the monster once, and drew it with 6 eyes like a spider's.) It came from the stars and was not made of terrene matter. In its first appearance, "The Call of Cthulhu",  it is stated that when its city R'lyeh sank beneath the ocean, it could no longer influence men with telepathic communication, because something about the ocean cut off all such broadcasts. Surely if it was aquatic, its powers would not be adversely affected by seawater.

After Lovecraft's death, August Derleth made Cthulhu a "water elemental", despite all the evidence to the contrary. So if Aquaman is in a Derleth story, yeah, he can control Cthulhu. If by some accident he blunders into Lovecraft's original, he's one more sardine for the Old One to gobble.

Comment: Do you have a link to the image that Lovecraft drew?

Comment: @Sardathrion, here is a link to the sketch HPL made of the Cthulhu idol. Assuming Cthulhu is symmetrical, he has 6 eyes like a spider, rather than 2 like an octopus. http://www.cynical-c.com/2010/05/19/cthulhu-as-drawn-by-hp-lovecraft/

Comment: @GomroMorskopp: Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 9):

Cthulhu has octopoid features and is trapped underwater, but he is not a sea creature. In fact, in "The Call of Cthulhu," it's mentioned that the water is actually a *bad* thing from his point of view, because it blocks his telepathic communications with the cult and keeps him and the rest of the Great Old Ones imprisoned. August Derleth tried to make him into a water elemental, but August Derleth can go jump in a lake.

Comment: rather, he can go jump in the cthulhu-filled ocean.

Answer (score 3):

Cthulhu is not of the sea. He is not of this world at all. He is simply sleeping there for some time.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it largely is based on the point in the Cthulu mythos evolution your talking about.

Early mythos: yes he was a great sea creature and a priest.

Late mythos: no, he was a god that was under the sphere of water.

Answer (score 0):

Aqua man doesn't use "mind control" for fish, he talks to and persuade them, he can bend them, but not force them to do his own bidding. Secondly, it also matters not because he can communicate telepathically with humans to, in one comic he caused one guy to have convulsions just by concentrating and caused the evil Kordax to kill himself by unleashing an intense mental attack.He can swim up to about 1000 knots (about 1,150 MPH) and has the body strength to throw a car like a football, so he could penetrate the skin of Cuthulhu with his trident while using his mental powers to annoy him. I think that they both would see no reason to kill each other unless they were hindering the other's progress and frankly think that they would make a good team. Besides, once a year Aquaman fights a cthulhu-like alien form another dimension, in which he has never lost. Aquaman can travel to different dimensions as well as time travel, perhaps where he lives, and maybe make allies with him.

Comment: I have a feeling that if Aquaman ever came into telepathic contact with Cthulhu, he would fail his sanity check.

Answer (score -1):

to the question, can Aquaman control humans in submarines- yes, he can control humans anywhere!

and considering he mind-controlled Tiamat into eternal damnation, yes, he absolutely could control Cthulu. pretty sure he has.

and the DC version of Cthulu (or, the Night Gods, anyway), live in a parallel dimension, and try to cross over into Earth's oceans once every year- always stopped by Aquaman.

Comment: Do you have a source for your information?