# Is there a Batman-Lovecraft connection?

Tags: dc, batman, inspiration, h-p-lovecraft

Arkham is the fictional town that many of Lovecraft's stories take place in. Arkham Asylum in Gotham is named from its founder. But with the line of Arkham-named Batman games, I cannot help but wonder, is there a reason why such a peculiar name from a public domain source is used so extensively in the Batman stories? It seems they would be wiser to have a name that could be copyrighted (since something from the public domain cannot be), but they chose to label an entire series with "Arkham". What might tie Batman to The Ancient Ones, I wonder??

This is not just whether there was an inspiration relation, but also whether there are in-universe connections, or other ties between the two universes.

Comment: Batman = Gothic. Gothic = Lovecraft.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. But they chose a public domain series title for a flagship game, which makes no sense. Is there really nothing more to it?

Comment: If you tried to use "Arkham" for a similar game, comic, cartoon or film, you'd get the pants sued off of you.

Comment: That is very obvious. But Arkham Typist or Arkham Karaoke would theoretically be within the law. I'm just wondering if there is an in-universe or comicbook writing history reason for using Arkham in such a central way...

Comment: Why would you want to make something called Arkham Karaoke? If the product is unrelated enough to avoid "passing off" then there's no benefit in using the trademark.

Comment: I have no idea ("Karaoke" was just off the top of my head), but if Arkham has Lovecraftian ties, it seems something Lovecraftian could use the name, for one. And since it's public domain, reason really does go out the window, so anyone might be using the name just for how cool it quite honestly sounds. It still makes no sense for DC/WB to put that kind of emphasis on a public domain name, IMHO. But I am starting to get that there is no bigger Arkham connection in the Batman universe than Arkham Asylum, is that right?

Comment: New, Arkham Karaoke! Scream along to the hymns of the Golden old ones! It's so...fun...you'll lose your mind!

Comment: @VapedCrusader Somehow, I get the Batman song from the LEGO movie in my head, instead...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was Arkham Asylum inspired by Lovecraft's favourite town?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104429/was-arkham-asylum-inspired-by-lovecrafts-favourite-town)

Comment: @Yasskier Yes and no. I think that question is a necessary part of answering mine. It seems it would fit in well here, but I am still interested in a broader connection. Which, as it happens, I feel the answers have very nicely given.

Comment: I tried to answer this question, but the vision of The Thing made me go insane.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - No, no - the Vision and the Thing are *Marvel* characters.

Comment: “they chose a public domain series title for a flagship game, which makes no sense.” The first game in the series was set entirely in Arkham Asylum, so it's a fairly sensible title there. It was a big success, so it makes sense to keep the distinctive name for the subsequent games. Have they been harmed by using a word in the title that can't be copyrighted? The games have done well, and I don't think there's been a rash of similarly-named products that have detracted from their success. So, the thing that makes no sense is your assertion that using 'Arkham' in the title makes no sense.

Comment: Relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126706/when-was-the-first-connection-to-arkham-asylum-in-batman-fiction

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## In-universe

Gotham City isn't in the same universe as Lovecraft's writings, but Lovecraftian monsters appeared in [Batman: The Doom that Came to Gotham](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Doom_That_Came_to_Gotham_Vol_1) in the year 2000. It is an [Elseworlds](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Elseworlds) story which isn't part of the main canon.

Arkham Asylum was named for its founder, Dr. Amadeus Arkham. He first appeared in [Arkham Asylum: A Serious House on Serious Earth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_Asylum:_A_Serious_House_on_Serious_Earth), in 1989 (according to the [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Amadeus_Arkham)). I don't know that the asylum had much backstory before that. It's only a coincidence that Dr. Arkham shares his name with the fictional town in H. P. Lovecraft's writings.

## Out-of-universe

Lovecraft was one of the inspirations for the stories of Batman, at least by the 1960s.

In the [*Batman* TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)), which first aired in **1966**, there was a villain named the Outsider, whose name was taken from a [short story by Lovecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outsider_(short_story)). (See *Batman: The Complete History*, page 102.)

Dennis O'Neil, one of the writers of Batman comics, stated that one of his influences was Lovecraft. From *Batman: The Complete History*, page 138, emphasis mine:

> This story, for *Detective Comics* #395 (January **1970**), presented Batman as a fish out of water, caught up in a Mexican horror tale about a wealthy couple who seek eternal life but end up crumbling into dust. This was a long way from Batgirl and the Batmobile, but O'Neil said, "I'm sure we didn't give that a second's thought. I just wanted to make it Gothic and spooky. **I was being influenced by writers like Lovecraft and Poe**, and I didn't think about Gotham City."

Arkham Asylum first appeared in **1974**, inspired by Lovecraft. From former DC Comics editor Jack C. Harris, emphasis mine:

> One summer, I immersed myself in the dark works of H. P. Lovecraft... It was during a conversation with writer Denny O'Neil, before I had even graduated from college, that I suggested that Batman villains such as Two-Face and Joker should never be housed in a common prison; they should be locked away in an insane asylum. And **what better asylum could there be for such maniacs than Arkham, the dark dwelling of the tormented souls from Lovecraft's horrific tales?** Denny agreed and used the idea, making Arkham my first contribution to the foundations of the Dark Age of Comics. (It's all there, in *Batman* #258, September [*should be [October](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/File:Batman_258.jpg)*] 1974, the true first appearance of Arkham Asylum in DC Comics...)
>
> —Foreword to *The Dark Age: Grim, Great & Gimmicky Post-Modern Comics*, page 5

The summer mentioned in that quotation may have been before 1970, which could explain O'Neil incorporating elements of Lovecraft into Batman in 1970; I couldn't find a date for when Harris graduated college.

Before 1966, I couldn't find any explicit mention of Batman being inspired by Lovecraft. Lovecraft published [The Picture in the House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Picture_in_the_House), his first story to feature the town of Arkham, Massachusetts, in 1921; the first Batman story was published in 1939. It's possible that Lovecraft had an influence over Batman from the beginning, but Lovecraft's writings were still fairly new when Batman debuted, and the genre hadn't had time to develop fully. On Wikipedia, the earliest work not written by Lovecraft to feature the town of [Arkham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkham) was published in 1937.

Comment: You can see the cover for Batman 258 on the [DC comics wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_258) which I linked to in my comment on AncientSwordRage's answer (click "full resolution" [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/File:Batman_258.jpg) to see it slightly larger), you can see it does say "OCT".

Comment: This is a great answer! Well sourced!

Answer (score 13):

The name is a homage to Lovecraft,  who has provided inspiration for writers for decades.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkham#Other_appearances) claims the use predates the games citing `Voger; Voglesong, Kathy (2006). The Dark Age: Grim, Great & Gimmicky Post-Modern Comics first1=Mark. TwoMorrows Publishing. p. 5. ISBN 1-893905-53-5.`

> The name was picked by editor Jack C. Harris and writer Dennis O'Neil in an homage to Lovecraft

There's no explicit connection,  besides Cthulhu's [occasional appearance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10101/3804) in DC comics.

It probably makes more sense to use a well known name for the location both in comics and the video game so add to make it more memorable and cut back on world building. Furthermore it reinforces the gothic,  dark and grim world of Batman as [Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126702/is-there-a-batman-lovecraft-connection#comment317210_126702) says:

> Batman = Gothic. Gothic = Lovecraft

Lovecraft practically invented modern gothic fiction, so it's an easy connection to make. Consider how many references fantasy works have to Tolkien, the fantasy equivalent.

Comment: If your comment "The wikipedia article claims the use predates the games" suggests you're unsure of the claim's accuracy, you can see the graphic novel [Arkham Asylum: A Serious House on Serious Earth](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_Asylum:_A_Serious_House_on_Serious_Earth) was published in 1989; also, [this page](http://www.supermanartists.comics.org/batman/batman.htm) lists various Batman "firsts", and for Arkham it shows [this page](http://www.supermanartists.comics.org/batman/Arkham-Batman258.JPG) which is from [*Batman #278*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_258), October 1974.

Comment: @hypnosifl I only said claims as I've not read the original book